# Dual boot for two drives (the second drive for Windows data and Linux file system)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi, boot-repair

I have dual boot for Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.04.3.
The specific of my parts is that the first drive is fully for Windows, and the second drive is parted for both Windows files (no boot part) and for Linux file system (with boot). Ubuntu had been installed on free space there, after creating part for Windows files.

After updating Windows my GRUB has broken, and it's starting in command line now.

In details: I have two SSD's (info shown by GParted):

- dev/nvme0n1:

  - dev/nvme0n1p1 (EFI part, 100 MiB)
  - dev/nvme0n1p2 (Microsoft reserved part, 16MiB)
  - dev/nvme0n1p3 (Basic data part, 930GiB)
  - dev/nvme0n1p4 (Unnamed part, don't know it's purpose, 444MiB)
- dev/sda:

  - dev/sda1 (Basic data part used by Windows, 172GiB)
  - dev/sda2 (EFI part, as I understand it's related to Ubuntu, 513MiB)
  - dev/sda3 (Linux file system, 292GiB)

I booted Windows and it normally works with sda1, but for sda2/sda3 parts GParted (from liveCD) shows `unable to detect file system` error.
UEFI shows me that Ubuntu and Windows boots are on the nvme0n1 drive and GRUB command line opens after booting Ubuntu. No info about boot on sda2 in UEFI.

So the first question: why after updating Windows has my GRUB broken?

The second question: is it normal that EFI on nvme0n1 has paths for Ubuntu and Windows both (I checked it in GRUB command line)? If it's OK, why do I need EFI part on sda2?

The third question: how can I fix GRUB without reinstalling Ubuntu and is it normal to have Windows on the first SSD and Windows data part + Ubuntu OS on the second SSD?

I tried to fix it with boot-repair application from LiveCD, however it has no button "recommended repair".
But I have [boot info summary](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vvjnHRB2n2/), maybe it will help.

Comment: If using Ubiquity installer with 22.04 & before grub only installs to "first" drive whatever UEFI/BIOS says is first.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 You also have old BIOS boot loaders in gpt's protective MBR. Just never try to boot in BIOS mode. See line 211 in report. It shows UUID that does not exist? Did you reinstall in BIOS mode, so UUID in UEFI mode not correct? Change fstab to use UUID of ESP on Ubuntu drive. Then in Boot-Repair's advanced mode totally reinstall grub. I used to like separate drives, but prefer systems on faster data on slower.

Comment: May you concertize, what should I change in fstab and from what: LiveCD or GRUB command line?

Comment: @oldfred, I didn't reinstall anything, just updated Windows while using Windows (after shutdown).
GRUB worked before it, but the next machine rebooting gave me GRUB command line.
After it I opened UEFI and it showed me two boots on the same SSD, the first priority was for Ubuntu.  
I tried to fix GRUB like here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329926/grub-starts-in-command-line-after-reboot from its command line, i think line 211 is result of it.

Comment: Showing a link with a variety of fixes, does not say exactly what you have tried. Post in question above exact steps used. Do you have correct ESP in fstab. Can you manually boot?